# pip django-easy-map SyntaxError and Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django

I decided to use django-easy-maps, but during the installation I got the error message bellow. It seems to have broken my Django, I can't run any more projects in it.

```
user@thunder-linux:/usr/local/lib$ pip install django-easy-maps
Downloading/unpacking django-easy-maps
  Downloading django-easy-maps-0.9.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-mFRe3s/django-easy-maps/setup.py) egg_info for package django-easy-maps

Downloading/unpacking django (from django-easy-maps)
  Downloading Django-1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6MB): 6.6MB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking django-appconf (from django-easy-maps)
  Downloading django_appconf-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking django-classy-tags==0.6.2 (from django-easy-maps)
  Downloading django_classy_tags-0.6.2-py2-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking geopy>=0.96 (from django-easy-maps)
  Downloading geopy-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB): 66kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking six (from django-appconf->django-easy-maps)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: django-easy-maps, django, django-appconf, django-classy-tags, geopy, six
  Running setup.py install for django-easy-maps

Compiling /tmp/pip-build-mFRe3s/django/django/conf/app_template/apps.py ...
  File "/tmp/pip-build-mFRe3s/django/django/conf/app_template/apps.py", line 4
    class {{ camel_case_app_name }}Config(AppConfig):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling /tmp/pip-build-mFRe3s/django/django/conf/app_template/models.py ...
  File "/tmp/pip-build-mFRe3s/django/django/conf/app_template/models.py", line 1
    {{ unicode_literals }}from django.db import models
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Successfully installed django-easy-maps django django-appconf django-classy-tags geopy six
Cleaning up...
user@thunder-linux:/usr/local/lib$
```

And after that, when I try to run my project:

```
user@thunder-linux:~/Documents/arq/dev/python/project$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 176, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 71, in get_commands
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
user@thunder-linux:~/Documents/arq/dev/python/project$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
user@thunder-linux:~/Documents/arq/dev/python/project$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 9, 0, 'final', 0)
```

## Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'project_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'project_app.templatetags.util_extras',
    # Pillow pip install python-pillow
    'imagekit',
    # Easy maps for GMapi
    'easy_maps',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Django 1.9. There are currently lots of third party packages that do not comply with the safe use of application (in the new model that Django implemented two versions ago). You will have to wait until the package is updated or try fixing it yourself in the meantime. Otherwise you might use Django 1.8.7.

Comment: Hummm. Ok. Thanks for the update. I have contacted the developer. Additionally, I will try to look into this problem myself.